# Where can HTTP status code be returned as I wish

Tags: http

I am looking for a web service that returns the HTTP code that I request to  test my scripts response to the codes.

Specifically, I am looking for **`201`**. This [project](http://httpstat.us/) seems to do the job for other status codes, but for 201, they don't send the `Location` header pointing to the location of the newly created resource.

Comment: Http status is basically generated with condition according to the results in general

Comment: Why don't you just mock out the HTTP call, which will be much faster and not reliant on a third party staying available?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an exemple on how to do this in php:

```
<?php
http_response_code(201);
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); 
?>
```

To verify that it's working you can use the **network** module of **firebug**.
I've tested it and the server send me a code 201 and the location header.
[image]

Best regards,
Gael.